# Recommendation for manipulating data with python vs. SQL for a django app

Tags: python, sql, django

Background:

I am developing a Django app for a business application that takes client data and displays charts in a dashboard.  I have large databases full of raw information such as part sales by customer, and I will use that to populate the analyses.  I have been able to do this very nicely in the past using python with pandas, xlsxwriter, etc., and am now in the process of replicating what I have done in the past in this web app.  I am using a PostgreSQL database to store the data, and then using Django to build the app and fusioncharts for the visualization.  In order to get the information into Postgres, I am using a python script with sqlalchemy, which does a great job.

The question:
There are two ways I can manipulate the data that will be populating the charts.  1) I can use the same script that exports the data to postgres to arrange the data as I like it before it is exported.  For instance, in certain cases I need to group the data by some parameter (by customer for instance), then perform calculations on the groups by columns.  I could do this for each different slice I want and then export different tables for each model class to postgres.

2) I can upload the entire database to postgres and manipulate it later with django commands that produce SQL queries.

I am much more comfortable doing it up front with python because I have been doing it that way for a while.  I also understand that django's queries are little more difficult to implement.  However, doing it with python would mean that I will need more tables (because I will have grouped them in different ways), and I don't want to do it the way I know just because it is easier, if uploading a single database and using django/SQL queries would be more efficient in the long run.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's the usual tradeoff between performances and flexibility. With the first approach you get better performances (your schema is taylored for the exact queries you want to run) but lacks flexibility (if you need to add more queries the scheam might not match so well - or even not match at all - in which case you'll have to repopulate the database, possibly from raw sources, with an updated schema), with the second one you (hopefully) have a well normalized schema but one that makes queries much more complex and much more heavy on the database server.

Now the question is: do you really have to choose ? You could also have both the fully normalized data AND the denormalized (pre-processed) data alongside.

As a side note: Django ORM is indeed most of a "80/20" tool - it's designed to make the 80% simple queries super easy (much easier than say SQLAlchemy), and then it becomes a bit of a PITA indeed - but nothing forces you to use django's ORM for everything (you can always drop down to raw sql or use SQLAlchemy alongside).

Oh and yes: your problem is nothing new - you may want to [read about OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, this was a very helpful answer, and good to validate that my dilemma is not unique (helps me confirm that I am just not misunderstanding the process entirely).  I like the suggestion about having all types of data available and will probably do that.  Appreciate the help.